# Eloquent query on relationship table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Hello i have two models **Adress** and **Kontokorrent** they have a one to one relationship. I would like to make a search function and search after **Adress** and **Kontokorrent** columns

My models:

**Adress Model**

```
class Adress extends Model
{
    protected $table = "Adressen";
    protected $primaryKey = 'Adresse';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function scopeSearchAdress($query, $searchTerm)
    {
        return $query->where('LieferOrt', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')
                     ->orWhere('Name1', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')
                     ->orWhere('LieferStrasse', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');              
    }

    public function kontokorrent()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Kontokorrent::class, 'Adresse');
    }
}
```

**Kontokorrent Model**

```
class Kontokorrent extends Model
{
    protected $table = "Kontokorrent";
    protected $primaryKey = 'Adresse';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function scopeSearchKto($query, $searchTerm)
    {
        return $query->where('Kto', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');              
    }

    public function adress()
    { 
        return $this->belongsTo(Adress::class, 'Adresse');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
class AdressesController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $searchTerm = $request->input('searchTerm');

        $adresses = Adress::whereHas('kontokorrent', function($query) use($searchTerm) {
            $query->where('KtoArt', 'D')
                  ->searchKto('K75688'); // this is working
                  // -> searchKto($searchTerm); this is NOT working       
        })->orderBy('Name1')
        ->searchAdress($searchTerm)
        ->paginate(60);

        return view('adresse.index', compact('adresses', 'searchTerm'));
    }
}
```

The search function in **Adress** model is working. Now i would like to search after the customer ID (Kto) in **Kontokorrent**. So i made a scope in **Kontokorrent** and chain it to the contoller search function.

`->searchKto('K75688')` .... this is working i get a result 
`->searchKto($searchTerm)` .... this is not working when i entry the customer id in my input field and hit enter. I get a 0 row table.

**View**

```
@section('content')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <form role="search" method="GET" action="/adresses">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchTerm" value="{{ isset($searchTerm) ? $searchTerm : '' }}" placeholder="Suche nach Name, Straße, Ort">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-search btn-default">
                       Suchen...
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Straße</th>
                    <th>Ort</th>
                    <th>PLZ</th>
                    <th>Land</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if(count($adresses) > 0)
                    @foreach($adresses as $adress)
                        <tr> 
                            <th scope="row">{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>   
                            <td>
                                <a href="/adresses/{{$adress->Adresse}}">{{$adress->Anrede}} {{ $adress->Name1}}</a>
                                @if($adress->kontokorrent)
                                <small>{{ $adress->kontokorrent->Kto }}</small>
                                @endif
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ $adress->LieferStrasse }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $adress->LieferOrt }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $adress->LieferPLZ }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $adress->LieferLand }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                @else
                    <tr><td colspan="6" class="text-center">Kein Eintrag gefunden.</td></tr>
                @endif
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
{{ $adresses->appends(['searchTerm' => $searchTerm])->links() }}
@endsection
```

I don't understand why I get an empty table.

Comment: Is `$request->input('searchTerm');` returning anything ?

Comment: yes this is working i can search in the adress model when i input a city name... but the kontokorrent model is not working when i search after the customer id

Comment: Did you try to call a SQL request directly on your database to verify that your request is working ?

Comment: yes,i do this always before i implement a query to laravel

Comment: i don't understand why a static value is working `->searchKto('K75688');` and when i replace it with a variable it's not working

Comment: initialize `$searchTerm = 'K75688'` manually to test. what do you have?

Comment: when i initialize it i get a result. i also noticed that when i comment out the `searchAdress($searchTerm)` `$searchTerm = $request->input('searchTerm');
        $adresses = Adress::whereHas('kontokorrent', function($query) use($searchTerm) {
            $query->where('KtoArt', 'D')
                  ->searchKto($searchTerm);      
        })
        ->orderBy('Name1')
        //->searchAdress($searchTerm)
        ->paginate(60);`  is working i can search after the customer id

Comment: can you `dd($searchTerm)` to see if the request makes it to that place?

Comment: i put the `dd($searchTerm)` in to the whereHas and yes i get the request